# In C++, how to check for errors when writing compressed files with gzstream?

Tags: c++, compression

I am using [gzstream](http://www.cs.unc.edu/Research/compgeom/gzstream/) to write outputs from my C++ program. However, sometimes the resulting file seems to be badly written: `zcat: output.txt.gz: unexpected end of file`, even though no error was returned by my own program.

Therefore, I would like to catch errors while writing the file, that is without having to wait until the program is finished to do a zcat and see the error above.

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
ogzstream outStream;
outStream.open ("output.txt.gz");
if (! outStream.is_open()) { cerr << "error while opening" << endl; exit (1); }
for (size_t i = 0; i < vecResults.size(); ++i)
    outStream << i << " " << vecResults[i] << endl;
outStream.close();
```

What can be improved? Should I check any error bit after writing with `<<`? Or after closing? If yes, how can I do that?

(FYI It's quite hard to replicate the error as it happens only rarely, but frequently enough to be annoying.)

Comment: Are you opening it in binary mode?

Comment: @Dani I'm opening it as written above, that is with the default `int open_mode = std::ios::in`

Comment: then of course it will fail. Open it in binary mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to check the result of `outStream.good()` after you close it, assuming the error checking is properly implemented internally.

Alternatively you could use the `exceptions(...)` member to request an exception to be thrown in case of errors.

Edit: the error bits are not reset automatically, so it's safe to just check them at the end; if anything fails in-between you can check at the end.

Comment: thanks, but at the end I decided to use Zlib directly instead of gzstream (which simply wraps it), and I'm checking the values returned by gzprintf and gzclose